# Laravel - joining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables: **users, visits, bloodtests**

The Tables look like this:

**users:**      id

**visits:**     id, user_id

**bloodtests:** id, visit_id

What I need to get is **"SELECT * FROM bloodtests" for the current user**

I tried this way:

```
$item = User::findOrFail($id);   //get ID of current user

$bt = DB::table('bloodtests')
    ->join('visits', 'bloodtests.visit_id', '=' ,'visits.id')
    ->join('users', 'visits.user_id', '=' ,'users.id')
    ->select(
        'bloodtests.id',  
        'bloodtests.visit_id')
    ->where('users.id', $item)
    ->get();
```

But it doesnt work.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: what kind of error does it shows? It is unclear.

Comment: the query returns nothing (should return 2 records - based on data in my DBs)

Comment: you can use `toSql()` method to check your sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$item = User::findOrFail($id);

$bt = DB::table('bloodtests')
    ->join('visits', 'bloodtests.visit_id', '=' ,'visits.id')
    ->join('users', 'visits.user_id', '=' ,'users.id')
    ->select(
        'bloodtests.id',  
        'bloodtests.visit_id')
    ->where('users.id', $item->id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting all users data as collection with this

```
 $item = User::findOrFail($id);
```

You just need to provide current user's id by `\Auth::id()` or direct using `$id` instead `$item`

```
$bt = DB::table('bloodtests')
    ->join('visits', 'bloodtests.visit_id', '=' ,'visits.id')
    ->join('users', 'visits.user_id', '=' ,'users.id')
    ->select(
        'bloodtests.id',  
        'bloodtests.visit_id')
    ->where('users.id', \Auth::id())
    ->get();
```

or direct using `$id`

```
->where('users.id', $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = User::findOrFail($id);   //get ID of current user

$bt = DB::table('bloodtests')
    ->join('visits', 'bloodtests.visit_id', '=' ,'visits.id')
    ->join('users', 'visits.user_id', '=' ,'users.id')
    ->select(
        'bloodtests.id',  
        'bloodtests.visit_id')
    ->where('users.id', $id)
    ->get();
```